# Has anyone experienced Flutter TextFormField keyboardType not working properly recently?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Has anyone ran into any issues with the Flutter keyboard type recently?

I am trying to use TextInputType.emailAddress on a TextFormField. It has its own controller.

The e-mail sign '@' and none of the other special characters are able to be selected.

```
 TextFormField(
                      controller: _loginController,
                      autocorrect: false,
                      //cursorColor: scaffoldFontColor,
                      style: TextStyle(color: scaffoldFontColor),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        email = value;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'E-mail address',
                      ),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                          return 'Invalid email address';
                        }
                      },
                    ),
```

I have ran and restarted the app several times.

Could this be a problem with iOS or Flutter internally?

I am unable to directly login to accounts now.

Comment: could u show us the code?

Comment: I just looked into some of the forms I have...they all have the same issue...none of the keyboards are showing special characters....its not iOS ....iOS works fine

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: yes solution was to upgrade flutter to newest version

Answer (score 0):

```
TextFormField(
      key: _emailKey,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
      autofocus: true,
      validator: (val) {
        if (val.trim().isEmpty) {
          return "Enter Email Address";
        } else if (!TextUtils.isValidEmail(val)) {
          return "Enter valid email address";
        } else {
          email = val;
        }
        return null;
      },
      onFieldSubmitted: (val) {
        if (_emailKey.currentState.validate()) {
          _emailKey.currentState.save();
          email));
        }
      },
      onSaved: (val) {
        email = val;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        hintText: 'E-Mail',
      ),
    );
```

Try it!